# How can I view specific instances of errors in Sentry

Tags: sentry

For instance:

I search for errors that happened to a specific user by searching for their email address in the search bar. That brings me back a list of errors. When I click on one of the errors it shows me a similar error that happened to a different user. How can I find the exact error that occurred for the user I searched for?

Thanks in advance,
Dan

Comment: FYI, what you call "error" is internally called an issue or *event group*, and a "specific error" is internally called an *event*. I think this should make searching for answers easier for you.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're talking about Sentry 9 (current version). Inside of an issue, go to the events tab:

[image: Tabbar with the tabs Details, Comments, User Feedback, Tags, Events, Merged, Similar Issues]

And there should be another search box to search for concrete events within that issue.

Answer (score 0):

Piggy-backing off of Markus' answer, I'd add that the syntax for this events search screen is different than the main search.

I found this issue:
https://github.com/getsentry/sentry/issues/2898

The syntax of event.timestamp is mentioned, however it doesn't work on the event page (perhaps because the event is implied?).

These examples work for zooming into a specific time and device:

```
timestamp:>2022-08-15 timestamp:<2022-08-17
timestamp:>2022-08-16T09:00:00 timestamp:<2022-08-16T16:18:00
device.family:SM-G990U
```